# ESP32 Firebase: authenticating results in error code 400 - but Firebase does recognize my login

Tags: c++, c, firebase, arduino, esp32

I am trying to authenticate using `signIn()` method and *exact replica of example code* from [ESP32 Client library (the new version)](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP-Client)

- When I run my code I successfully connect to `WiFi` and also I can
  successfully `CREATE` new account from the ESP32 board.
- I need to know if my log in or registration was successful
- In my `Firebase authentication` signup with `email/pass` is enabled.

**In my serial monitor I can read that the `error code is 400` this:**

[image]

[image]

**Code that I am using:**

```
Serial.printf("Firebase Client v%s\n\n", FIREBASE_CLIENT_VERSION);

/* Assign the api key (required) */
fb_config.api_key = API_KEY;

/* Assign the user sign in credentials */
fb_auth.user.email = email_name.c_str();
fb_auth.user.password = email_name.c_str();

/* Assign the RTDB URL */
fb_config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
fb_do.setResponseSize(4096);

/* Assign the callback function for the long running token generation task */
fb_config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback; //see addons/TokenHelper.h

/** Assign the maximum retry of token generation */
fb_config.max_token_generation_retry = 5;

/* Initialize the library with the Firebase authen and config */
Firebase.begin(&fb_config, &fb_auth);

if(Firebase.authenticated()){
  Serial.println("I am authenticated");
} else {
  Serial.println("Well I AM NOT???");
}
```

**Screenshot from my Firebase authentication that my ESP32 was created and also logged in today:**

[image]

**I know my Firebase initialization was successful because I can read and write read data into the Realtime database:**

[image]

**I am using `PlatformIO` and this is my config file:**

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
build_flags = -D PIO_FRAMEWORK_ARDUINO_MMU_CACHE16_IRAM48_SECHEAP_SHARED
lib_deps = 
    mobizt/Firebase Arduino Client Library for ESP8266 and ESP32@^2.5.4
    bblanchon/ArduinoJson@^6.18.5
```

Comment: What if you run the [signup](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP-Client) example? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes I am using the `singup` example. If you look at my code it is exactly the same - with the exception of not using the helper functions (which are RTDB related anyway). Or am I missing something from the example code?

Comment: I'm asking a simple question on have you try the exact code used by the example.  If you think your code is "exactly" the same, then I have no further comment.

Comment: Okay I have copy pasted the same program as from the example. Unfortunately same result - ESP32 is not authenticated. I can see now in the helper functions that they return `error code 400`

Comment: I have edited my entire question. Please take a look.

Comment: This is something else, if it is authentication error, it would be 403 instead of 400. Do you have the correct path (URL endpoint, uid, etc.)? I noticed that you had `base_path` but didn't show how you use it.

Comment: I think my `URL_endpoint` is correct because when I use it to read from `RTDB` everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem was that I was checking for the
  `Firebase.authenticated()` method too early, and the Firebase did not
  have time to authenticate.
- If I check it in the main `loop()` it works.

*GitHub [discussion](https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP-Client/discussions/153) where we find the solution.*